# Analyzing a Kawasaki-evolving Ising model? (conserved-order-parameter Ising model)

Tags: phase-transition, ising-model, critical-phenomena

*Focusing on 2D in further text*

I am struggling to understand how the conserved-order-parameter Ising model (also known/reached through Kawasaki algorithm) shows criticality and also how it can be compared to the usual Ising model (order parameter, critical temperature, exponents and so on).

I am aware they share the same universality class and should provide the same critical exponents, but I can't seem to understand what will be behaving as the order parameter. Since magnetisation is fixed, the system obviously can't behave in the usual sense with regards to low temperature, so it separates into two distinct phases, one pointing up and the other down. It can also just be completely random and homogenous, depending on the density. But what is the observable showing the phase transition then? These "special" density values depend on magnetisation, so they don't seem right. Also, there is not a single critical value of density, at least it seems so.

This is an old topic but for some reason, finding literature on it has been nearly impossible and I ended up finding just one or two printed copies with very scarce descriptions.